# printing the 1st letter of the first 3 words using split() python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, split

This is my code so far for getting the string of the 1st letters of each word in a string but when I return it to main it does not print anything.

```py
def phrases(string):
    result2 = ''

    for letter in string.split():
        result2 += letter[0]

    return result2

def main():

    string = input('Please enter a string: ')
    replacePhrases = input('Do you want to replace phrases? ')

    if replacePhrases == 'y' or replacePhrases == 'Y':    
        result2 = phrases(string)
        print(result2)
```

Comment: I assume you are calling `main()` (though it's not shown in your code snippet) and in which case this works perfectly.

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine. Ensure you are calling `main()`. -- Austin got there like a bullet!

Comment: @Austin yes sorry I forgot to put it in there !

Comment: @Glazbee I did call main but I forgot to upload it as well. Unfortunately it did not work still

Comment: It is working perfectly. Just it works when you answer "yes" to the question "Do you want to replace phrases" which is probably not the behavior you wanted

Comment: What do you input exactly ?

Comment: @Clément Oh my god, the whole time ive done yes instead of y for input. Thank you!